Dynamically get all RelatedList from particular record
I have some problem with getting related lists from Contact.
I have in this contactRecord, few related lists.
Now by using Schema and childRelationships() i want to check if any of my related list has a value but .get method on the Contact record not working.
Here is my snippet:
    ``` Contact contactRecord = getContactsStore().getContactWithRelatedLists(newContact.Id);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.ChildRelationship> C = R.getChildRelationships();

        if (contactRecord != NULL) {
            for (Schema.ChildRelationship chRelationship :C) {
                String relationshipName = chRelationship.getRelationshipName();
                if (relationshipName != NULL) {
                    List<SObject> relatedRecords = (List<SObject>)contactRecord.get(relationshipName);
                    if (relatedRecords != null && !relatedRecords.isEmpty()) {
                        newContact.addError('examp err');
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }



You need to use getSObjects instead of using get to retrieve the related records. The get method returns the value for the field specified by the field token Schema.sObjectField and the getSObjects method returns the values for the specified field. This method is primarily used with dynamic DML to access values for associated objects, such as child relationships.
Contact contactRecord = getContactsStore().getContactWithRelatedLists(newContact.Id);
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> C = R.getChildRelationships();

if (contactRecord != NULL) {
        for (Schema.ChildRelationship chRelationship : C) {
                String relationshipName = chRelationship.getRelationshipName();
                if (relationshipName != NULL) {
                        List<SObject> relatedRecords = (List<SObject>)contactRecord.getSObjects(relationshipName);
                        if (relatedRecords != null && !relatedRecords.isEmpty()) {
                                newContact.addError('Example error: Related list ' + relationshipName + ' has records.');
                        }
                }
        }
}


There are three methods on sObject that return different things. get, getSObject, and getSObjects. get returns field values, getSObject returns a parent related record, and getSObjects returns child related records. To get the related child records, use getSObjects.
